# Safari/Chrome overlapping elements that are set with inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a page to display two images side by side.  I want these items centered on the screen in a book format and as the browser is resized, the images height is changed so they fill the window.

In order to do this I am using display inline-block with text-aligned center to achieve the affect. IT works great on FF but when I open in Safari or Chrome on resize the divs begin to overlap.  I created this jsfiddle to show an example of my dom. I need the pageOne and pageTwo divs inline-block because later I absolutely position links on top of the page images.

What am I missing?

In order to see that issue, you'll need to open the jsFiddle in safari/chrome and make the result pane larger than the default. Start with your Browser about 1/2 its normal width/height.  As you run the jsFiddle, enlarge your browser and notice how the two images begin to overlap. If you open it in FF they wont overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/X9NNh/1

I was able to get close to the effect I want in all the browsers with this using tables:

http://jsfiddle.net/x82uK/

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that if they overlap when expanding the browser and they move apart when i decrease the browser.. in FF they stay butted (sp?) agains each other which is the effect i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is tricky because those inline-block containers don't resize themselves to fit their contents as their contents scale.

Though it will make your job harder (read: require Javascript) when it comes to absolutely positioning links atop the images, [here's an alternative approach](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYkV/1/) using `background-size: contain`.

HTML:

```
<div id="issue">
  <div id="leftPage" class="page" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/304/400);"></div>
  <div id="rightPage" class="page" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/304/400);"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
}
#issue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px; right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #EEE;
}
.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px; bottom: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
#leftPage {
  background-position: center right;
  left: 30px; right: 50%;
}
#rightPage {
  background-position: center left;
  left: 50%; right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Never thought about using this approach... I will have to give it a shot. I do lazy loading of the images so Ill have to write a new plugin to lazy load and replace the background url I suppose... and yes the absolute positioning of my links will be trickier b/c I dont know what the actual width of the div.page is.  I guess I can determine the aspect ratio of the image and figure out the width based on the container height... but yes this is worth trying out. Thanks!

Comment: You actually gave me a great idea with your comment "inline-block containers don't resize themselves to fit their contents as their contents scale" !  I just added a snippet of code to my resize handler to adjust the width of the .page container to be the width of the img in it.. and now it works in safari, chrome, and ff.  http://jsfiddle.net/X9NNh/3/

Comment: yeah the resize width based on the image is wonky... back to the drawing board.

Comment: I did not end up using this approach, but it was a great concept.  I ended up just using display:inline and using the container to determine the positioning based on the offset of the imgs in the container.